# Event Handling Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

in a map I want when the user clicks inside the map to be able to draw with his mouse a scheme. For example it clicks and then circles an area just by moving his mouse. The problem is that when he circles the area, continues to draw at the current mouse position.

In other words I want the user to click for start drawing and click again to stop it.

I am using addEventListener and removeEventListener
I am trying to remove the events from the map but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
map.addEventListener('click', goInter, false);

function goInter() { 

    map.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
    map.addEventListener('click', close, false);

    var pointList = [];
    var first_element;  
    var trig = 0;   


        function move(e) {
                map.dragging.disable();

                pointList[pointList.length] = new L.LatLng(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);

                first_element = pointList[0];

                //ama to valw den doulebei tipota!!
                //document.getElementById("elements").innerHTML =       pointList[ii++];

                if (pointList.length > 400){
                    pointList = [];
                }

                var line = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
                    color: 'red',
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 0.5,
                });

                map.addLayer(line);

                if (trig == 1){
                    map.preventDefault();
                    alert("den einai 1");
                    return false;
                }
        };

        function close(){
            //map.removeEventListener ('mousemove', move, false);
            var last_points = [first_element,      pointList[pointList.length-1]];
            var last_connection = new L.Polyline(last_points, { 
                color: 'blue', 
                weight: 1, 
                opacity: 0.9
            });

            map.addLayer(last_connection);
            trig = 1;
            map.preventDefault();

            //map.removeLayer(line);
            //map.fitBounds(line.getBounds());
        };
  };
```

- I have a progress -> i changed the two click events to -> mouseup and mousedown respectively. That gives me a better interaction. when the user releases the button it stops drawing. However if you press it again it draws. **ALSO uncomment first line of close() function**

Comment: Please show us some of your code what you have already tried.

Comment: Ok i found the solution, thanks for the try at least :)